# How extract a folder name to a file path with msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

I have a path for compilation :
C:\FolderA\Folder16-9\ForderC\FolderD

I want to extract the name of the second folder "Folder16-9" to put in a variable and use it after for compilation destination path.

How I can extract this folder name? is it possible with MSBuild scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example code

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="Test">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <ExamplePath>C:\FolderA\Folder16-9\ForderC\FolderD</ExamplePath>
            <SecondPart>$(ExamplePath.Split('\')[2])</SecondPart>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <Message Text="$(ExamplePath)" />
        <Message Text="$(SecondPart)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

will output

```
         C:\FolderA\Folder16-9\ForderC\FolderD
         Folder16-9
```

String methods can be used on properties. The example code is splitting the string on '/' and from the resulting array is using the value of index 2.

In the example, I defined the test value as a property. If you need to work with Item metadata, e.g. `%(FullPath)`, note that property functions can't be used on metadata and the metadata will need to pulled out into a property.